# Почему анимация не заканчивается?

Tags: android

Первый view летит ко второму и исчезает. Но потом не появляется. А вроде бы, после конца анимации - все должно встать на свои места.

```
    view.animate()
            .x(view2.getX())
            .y(view2.getY())
            .alpha(0.0f)
            .scaleX(0.0f)
            .setDuration(500)
            .start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Анимация могут быть разные в вашем случае это  ViewPropertyAnimator, изменяют параметры view. Поэтому после завершения анимации в вашем случае View будет иметь `getAlpha = 0f getX = 0f.`

Вам скорей всего подойдет ViewAnimation, он не преобразует value. И после окончания view отрисуется с первоначальными данными.

```
<set android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.4"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.6"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:duration="700" />
    <set android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
        <scale
           android:fromXScale="1.4"
           android:toXScale="0.0"
           android:fromYScale="0.6"
           android:toYScale="0.0"
           android:pivotX="50%"
           android:pivotY="50%"
           android:startOffset="700"
           android:duration="400"
           android:fillBefore="false" />
        <rotate
           android:fromDegrees="0"
           android:toDegrees="-45"
           android:toYScale="0.0"
           android:pivotX="50%"
           android:pivotY="50%"
           android:startOffset="700"
           android:duration="400" />
    </set>
</set>

ImageView spaceshipImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.spaceshipImage);
Animation hyperspaceJumpAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.hyperspace_jump);
spaceshipImage.startAnimation(hyperspaceJumpAnimation);
```

PS для бесконечной анимации есть параметр repeatCount         `android:repeatCount="infinite"`, *могу ошибиться поправьте исправьте если что сяп.*

> Пример:

по аналогии вашего вопрос кроме translate, но я думаю вы сообразите быстро на рабочем примере.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_activity);

    ImageView ivCoin = findViewById(R.id.iv_coin);
    ivCoin.setOnClickListener(v -> v.startAnimation(getCoinAnimSet()));
}


private AnimationSet getCoinAnimSet(){
    AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(true);

    AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1f, 0f);
    alphaAnimation.setDuration(500);
    alphaAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    alphaAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);

    ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(1f, 0f, 1f, 1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    scaleAnimation.setDuration(500);
    scaleAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    scaleAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);

    animationSet.addAnimation(alphaAnimation);
    animationSet.addAnimation(scaleAnimation);

    return animationSet;
}
```

анимация типо крутится монетка

Comment: Благодарю. А реально ли подставлять координаты "цели", как у меня в примере? У меня просто к одному объекту будут "скакать" несколько. И я не уверен в том, как на разных экранах будет работать, если задавать явным образом.

Comment: Либо я просто ошибаюсь и экраны не помеха, главное правильно задать.

Comment: Если хотите учитывать смещения для всех экранов, не используйте абсолютные величины. Я понимаю что это звучит немного, абсурдно ведь все анимации их используют px, но для этого можно написать утилитарный класс который использует dp для анимаций, тогда погрешность свидеться к минимуму. Кстати хорошей практикой считается использовать соотношения, например шарик летит в правую часть экрана на 75% от его длины, тогда для всех экранов это будет тоже примерно одинаково. Есть нюансы канеш и подводные камни, но это просто микро советы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Но мне, получается, придется для всех элементов прописывать свои анимации, так как движение к конкретной точке невозможно.

Comment: Так как там все способы для относительных перемещений.

Comment: В теории я могу задать смещение с помощью разности координат, верно? Но остается тогда вопрос с неизменяемым XML-файлом. Какие еще инструменты есть, которые позволят 1) Не менять свойства 2)Динамически задать смещение.?

Comment: ViewAnimation можно юзать динамически, вас никто не обязывает делать это в xml. это просто пример для вас. сейчас скину пример 5 сек

Comment: Спасибо, поковыряю эту вещь.

Comment: А не подскажете, почему я в проекте не могу использовать лямбды, как вы? Пишет, что версия языка низкая...

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html